# Displays the first image that was read by the loop

Tags: java, android, imageview

I would like to display the corresponding image of the letter that the user has been inputted. But the thing is, the loop repeatedly display the first image that was been read.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null, true);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);
    }

    for (int loop = 0; loop < ALPHA.length; loop++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphaSplit.length; j++) {
            if (alphaSplit[j] == ALPHA[loop]) {
                imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[loop]);
            }
        }
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

THIS IS ALREADY MY MODIFIED GET VIEW

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    for (int loop = 0; loop < alphaSplit.length; loop++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHA.length; j++) {
            if (alphaSplit[loop] == ALPHA[j]) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

BUT IT WOULD DISPLAY THE LAST CORRESPONDING IMAGE THE LOOP HAD FETCH

Comment: what is the problem actually? you want to get the first image in the inner loop or what?

Comment: Your first 5 lines looks goofy. You're inflating a rowView, then re-inflating it with convert view?  It looks like that whole convertview line is useless. There might lie your problem.

Comment: @Elltz i want to display whether the if statement is true

Comment: @hitch.united I already modified my code. But nothing changed. It displays repeatedly the first image

Comment: and it always checks out to be false? log the values and see if you actually get a match

Comment: @Elltz ok, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: if you havent still solved it let me know okay

Comment: @Elltz I already check if the values get a match. And it does.. my problem now is the image that will display is the last corresponding image that has been fetch by the loop

Comment: yea i get you, it might sound really weird but do you know the viewholder technique? please use it on the imageView and see

Comment: @Elltz I already used the viewholder technique. the same as what is answered below.

Answer (score 1):

You got the whole `getView` idea wrong.

First, don't define `LayoutInflater` over and over again. Create a constructor for your adapter and have it get `Context` as a parameter.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
public YourAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Second, use `convertView` wisely by setting a static holder as its tag:

```
static class Holder{
    ImageView imageView;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(...); //I'd recommend setting it (*layout, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    for (int loop = 0; loop < ALPHA.length; loop++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphaSplit.length; j++) {
            if (alphaSplit[j] == ALPHA[loop]) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[loop]);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

See, the check for `convertView == null` is used to define and inflate only the first visible views. Then you want to update the data inside the same views, so that it creates an illusion of scrolling (without actually inflating new views every time).

Comment: NPE is found: `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, null);`

Comment: replace his inflater with yours so you get rid of the NPE and life's good

Comment: This has nothing to do with the way it inflates your layout... Please elaborate on the errors you get now. Also, I saw your edited post and now the problem seems to be your own loops which I did not check. Adapter-wise, you're fine

Comment: @SaharAvr yes. my loop was wrong. but my problem is it only displays the last item the loop  would fetch